# Exchange 2010 Roll Up Patching Q

Tags: windows, email, exchange-2010

Our Exchange 2010 server is currently patched at SP2 RollUp 1.  I would like to update it to SP2 RU4 but I'm wondering if I can immediately update from RU1 to RU4 or do I have to go in succession RU2,3,4?

I'm guessing I can skip RU2 and RU3 and immediately patch to RU4.  Can someone please let me know if patches are cumulative?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are cumulative.

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637979.aspx

> Update rollup packages are cumulative. For example, if you apply Update Rollup 4 on a computer that is running Exchange 2010, you receive all the fixes in that specific update package together with all the fixes that were released in all earlier update rollup packages. That is, in Update Rollup 4, you receive all the updates that were released in the previous Update Rollup 1 through Update Rollup 3 packages plus the updates in Update Rollup 4.